# Null check operator used on a null value happening only in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When lauching my app in release mode (using `flutter run --release`) or by building an apk, I get strange behaviors, as if `setState()` was not entierly reloading the widgets.

When launching `flutter run --release --verbose`, I get the following message:

```
 flutter: Null check operator used on a null value
[   +1 ms] flutter: #0      ContainerRenderObjectMixin._insertIntoChildList (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:4192)
[        ] flutter: #1      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.insert (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:4225)
[        ] flutter: #2      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6810)
[        ] flutter: #3      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6569)
[        ] flutter: #4      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6436)
[        ] flutter: #5      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6878)
[        ] flutter: #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326)
[        ] flutter: #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837)
[        ] flutter: #8      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496)
[        ] flutter: #9      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187)
[        ] flutter: #10     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453)
[        ] flutter: #11     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447)
[        ] flutter: #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326)
[        ] flutter: #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3831)
[        ] flutter: #14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496)
[        ] flutter: #15     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634)
[        ] flutter: #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187)
[        ] flutter: #17     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2895)
[        ] flutter: #18     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:984)
[        ] flutter: #19     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:457)
[        ] flutter: #20     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1325)
[        ] flutter: #21     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1255)
[        ] flutter: #22     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113)
[        ] flutter: #23     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312)
[        ] flutter: #24     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:383)
[        ] flutter: #25     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283)
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[  +82 ms] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[        ] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
[+1002 ms] flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
```

`flutter: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'` error message go on for around 50 lines after.

Since I have no idea where the problem would be, here is a link to the code:
https://github.com/apoleon33/cradle .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, I was nesting `ScrollView`, as inside my `RefreshIndicator` I had a `SingleChildScrollView`, which was probably causing troubles for `setState`

changing my code to this did the trick:

```dart
RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _refreshData,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Column(
                children: albumCards,
              )),
```